# How to assign new variables after group_split by automatically?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I try do split a dataframe by two variables, year and sectors. I did split them with group_split but everytime I need them, I have to call them with $ operator. I want to give them a name automatically so I do not need to use $ for every usage. I know I can assign them to new names by hand but I have more than 70 values so it's a bit time consuming

```
dummy <- data.frame(year = rep(2014:2020, 12),
                    sector = rep(c("auto","retail","sales","medical"),3),
                    emp = sample(1:2000, size = 84))

dummy%>%
    group_by(year)%>%
    group_split(year)%>%
    set_names(nm = unique(dummy$year)) -> dummy_year

head(dummy_year$2014)

    
year    sector  emp
<int>   <chr>  <int> 
2014    auto    171     
2014    medical 1156        
2014    sales   1838        
2014    retail  1386        
2014    auto    1360        
2014    medical 1403
```

I want to call them like

```
some_kind_of_function(dummy_year, assign new variable by date) 

head(year_2014)
year    sector  emp
<int>   <chr>  <int> 
2014    auto    171     
2014    medical 1156        
2014    sales   1838        
2014    retail  1386        
2014    auto    1360        
2014    medical 1403
```

maybe a for loop?

Comment: Btw, `group_by(year) %>% group_split(year)` is redundant, `group_split(year)` is enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group_split` wouldn't create named `list`.  We can use `split` from `base R`

```
lst1 <- split(dummy, dummy$year)
names(lst1) <- paste0('year_', names(lst1))
```

If we want to create objects (not recommended), use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
> year_2014
   year  sector  emp
1  2014    auto  740
8  2014 medical  123
15 2014   sales  700
22 2014  retail  166
29 2014    auto  323
36 2014 medical  653
43 2014   sales  986
50 2014  retail 1814
57 2014    auto 1381
64 2014 medical  661
71 2014   sales 1362
78 2014  retail  641
```

Comment: But he still could use it in combination with `purrr::set_names()`? E.g.   `group_split(year) %>% purrr::set_names(nm = paste0("year_",unique(dummy$year)))`, then he can stay in his pipe structure.

Comment: Why do you not recommend using list2env? It is what I am looking for. Will it disrupt other objects?

Comment: @Julian Yes, but isn't it more convoluted compared to base R `split` which automatically creates a named list

Comment: @pimaniye41 I would prefer to keep it in a list and then extract as `lst1$year_2014` instead of creating more objects in the global env

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
dummy %>% 
  split(f = paste0("year_", as.factor(.$year)))
```